# Changing BindingContext in listView template does not point to Viewmodel

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

When changing BindingContext for a button in listView by adding

```
      BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference parentContePage}}"
      Command="{Binding ViewPdf}"
```

for some reason the app is trying to find the method in the view class instead and i am getting error in the output console

```
[0:] Binding: 'ViewPdf' property not found on 'WinterEventMobileForm.UI.Pages.ReservationView'
```

The parentContePage element

```
<views:MvxContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                      x:Name="parentContePage"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                x:TypeArguments="viewModels:ReservationViewModel"
                xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
                xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WinterEventMobileForm.Core.ViewModels;assembly=WinterEventMobileForm.Core" 
                xmlns:navigationdrawer="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfNavigationDrawer.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfNavigationDrawer.XForms" 
                xmlns:buttons="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Buttons;assembly=Syncfusion.Buttons.XForms" 
                xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WinterEventMobileForm.UI.Pages"
                xmlns:ListView="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.ListView.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms" 
                xmlns:core="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Core;assembly=Syncfusion.Core.XForms"
                x:Class="WinterEventMobileForm.UI.Pages.ReservationView" 
                xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WinterEventMobileForm.UI.Controls" xmlns:border="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Border;assembly=Syncfusion.Core.XForms"
                      Title="test"
                NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
                        xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Bindings;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
                >
```

Why is the x:Reference returning View instead of ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by modifing Command to:

```
Command="{Binding ViewModel.ViewPdf}"
```